# How to publish on SlideMe?

Tags: android

I have been trying to publish some apps, and got error:

Applications built from web builders, open-source content, tutorials, or from purchased pre-built assets must provide significant additional content and functionality.

What it's mean? What webbuilders? What Open-source?

What about they talk?

Comment: It means they think you have copied your app and it's not your own work. You have to change a example you use that far that it is something new.

Comment: Some stupid store :(

Comment: Try to reformat your code, use some auto refactoring methods of android studio. Probly it will change your code that far, that it is not recordnized as copy from other source anymore.